# biblatex + verbose - urldate is getting ignored

Tags: biblatex

I'm using `biblatex` with my own Bibstyle based on verbose Style.

```
\usepackage[bibstyle=mystyle,citestyle=mystyle,natbib=true]{biblatex}
```

Now I need the urldate shown in cite. But I can't find a way to do this.

I tried

```
\printfield{urldate}
```

But nothing.

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\url{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{formaturl}{\newline #1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{abrufurl}{\addcomma\space Abruf am #1}

\renewbibmacro*{url+urldate}{%
     \printtext[formaturl]{%
   \printfield{url}}%
     \printtext[abrufurl]{%
       \printfield{urldate}}%
}
```

Anyone could Help?

Comment: urldate isn't a field in the .bbl - it is split into the component urlyear/urlmonth/urlday by the backend. See the biblatex manual. That's why the pseudo-field macros like `\printurldate` exist.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At least with the standard `verbose` style, it works if you replace `\printfield{urldate}` with `\printurldate`. You might also want to change the format of `urldate` and load (as recommended in the `biblatex` manual) the [`babel`](http://ctan.org/pkg/babel) package, here with the `ngerman` option.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage[style=verbose]{biblatex}

\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\url{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{formaturl}{\newline #1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{abrufurl}{\addcomma\space Abruf am #1}

\renewbibmacro*{url+urldate}{%
     \printtext[formaturl]{%
   \printfield{url}}%
     \printtext[abrufurl]{%
       \printurldate}%
}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
  url = {tex.stackexchange.com},
  urldate = {2012-05-22},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\nocite{*}

\begin{document}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Instead of defining a new format including the string "Abruf am", you may also redefine existing bibliography strings:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage[style=verbose]{biblatex}

\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\newline\url{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{\addcomma\space\bibstring{urlseen}\space#1}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{%
  urlseen = {Abruf am},
}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
  url = {tex.stackexchange.com},
  urldate = {2012-05-22},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\nocite{*}

\begin{document}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Output for both examples:

[image]

Comment: OK, this solves the problem. I used @ online for the definition - with @ misc urldate is used. THX