# Which bibliographystyle for lastchecked and URL attribute?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I noticed that `lastchecked` and `URL` are non-standard attributes for a bibTeX files, which is kind of strange nowadays, but that's a different matter.

I tried to use `@misc{...}` with `itmalpha` style, but my document doesn't show the two attributes. Which style can I use for it to display, which doesn't mess up my other references, which are articles and incollections (for now).

Comment: You might consider to switch to `biblatex`, where you can control which fields are printed.

Comment: @Guido Can you point me to a good documentation (or the exact part in the manual) where I can control which fields are printed?

Comment: What you can do in `biblatex` is to redefine some macros. For example `\renewbibmacro{finentry}{\printfield{url}, \printdate{urldate}}`.  You can look at chapter 4 of the manual, a good intro is at  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12806/guidelines-for-customizing-biblatex-styles.

Comment: Oh. I actually found my problem. I used the `lastchecked` field instead of the `urldate` field. `urldate` would be the correct use in my case. Then the solution would be here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56904/biblatex-verbose-urldate-is-getting-ignored

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In most bibtex styles the information about url and the date when the web page has been accessed can be stored in the `howpublished` field (in free format).

A second alternative is to modify the `itmalpha` style to accommodate the two fields. The styles does not support `url` and `lastchecked`. Thus the first step is to insert these two fields in the `ENTRY` part of  the style:

```
ENTRY
  { address
    ...
    lastchecked
    url
    ...
  }
  {}
  { label extra.label sort.label }
```

Then, we create a function to print the value  of the fields. Thus we insert the following code in the file

```
FUNCTION {format.url.lastchecked}
{
  url empty$
    'skip$
    { "Available at: \url{" url * "}" * 
      lastchecked empty$
        'skip$
        { "Accessed on: "  lastchecked * }
      if$
    }
  if$
}
```

Finally, we have to use the function at the appropriate position (in the definition of `misc`). We can replace the  definition of `misc` with

```
FUNCTION {misc}
{ output.bibitem
  author empty$                               % added by R.Bless
    { format.editors output.nonnull }          % added by R.Bless
    { format.authors "author" output.check }   % added by R.Bless
  if$
  title howpublished new.block.checkb
  format.title output
  howpublished new.block.checka
  howpublished output
  organization output
  institution output
  format.date output
  fin.entry
  format.url.lastchecked output
  new.block
  note output
  fin.entry
  empty.misc.check
}
```

Instead of editing the `itmalpha.sty` file, please make a copy, edit it, and rename it (e.g. `myitmalpha.sty`).

PS I have used `\url{}` to wrap the value of the bibtex `url` field, this requires to load an appropriate style, e.g., `url` or `hyperref`.

Comment: Thanks for all the information. I followed your advice and looked at `biblatex`. Still somewhat complicated, but will look more into it. Changing the styles directly is an option I guess, but too tiresome in my case, because I'm still not quite sure which style to stick with.

Answer (score 3):

all styles here http://archiv.dante.de/~herbert/Bibliography/ know the fields `url` and `urldate`

Comment: The link is broken.

Comment: it is corrected ...